# Have 3 Monitors Display the same thing? (WinXP)

Tags: windows, display, clone, mirroring, duplicate

I have a setup in which there is a Computer running windows XP, with 3 monitors plugged into it, with a "Matrox Millennium P750" Graphics card.

What I want is to enable mirroring of ALL THREE MONITORS, meaning I want all the monitors to display the same image.

In Matrox Powerdesk, it does not have an option to do this, and I'm pretty sure that Windows XP does not support it nativley.

I really should only need some software/drivers, right?

What can i do to display the same thing on 3 screens?

Answer (score 1):

Download "Ultramon"  That should allow you to do what you want.

http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/

Comment: Ok, ANyone know of a free option?

Answer (score 0):

UltraMon is definitely a great program. Here is a link that contains free alternatives to UltraMon.

http://alternativeto.net/software/ultramon/?license=free